# Product price based on cookie data - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, woocommerce, price

I have a custom popup on website load and store the selected option in the cookie, I want to change the price of the product based on the selected option.

I have added meta boxes for price based on those option in the product, for simple and variable product.

And retrieve that prices at frontend, please check below code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price',  'return_price_by_option', 10, 2 );

function return_price_by_option( $price, $product ) {

    // options can be digits like 1, 2, 3, ...
    $option = isset( $_COOKIE['option'] ) ? $_COOKIE['option'] : '';

    if( $option ) {
        $regMKey    = '_sale_price_option_' . $option;
        $optPrice   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $regMKey, true );

        if( empty($optPrice) ) {
            $regMKey    = '_regular_price_option_' . $option;
            $optPrice   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $regMKey, true );
        }
        return $optPrice;
    }
    return $price;
}

// Also used two more filter for regular and sale price,
// Function have same code, but just return the price for same meta key 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'return_regular_price_by_option', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price',  'return_sale_price_by_option'), 10, 2 );
```

It works fine for simple products, 
But, not working for variable products, can anyone please help me for variable products? please suggest any easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Add follows code snippet to change price for variable and variations products -

```
function return_price_by_option( $price, $product ) {
    // delete product cache
    wc_delete_product_transients( $product->get_id() );

    // options can be digits like 1, 2, 3, ...
    $option = isset( $_COOKIE['option'] ) ? $_COOKIE['option'] : '';

    if( $option ) {
        $regMKey    = '_sale_price_option_' . $option;
        $optPrice   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $regMKey, true );

        if( empty($optPrice) ) {
            $regMKey    = '_regular_price_option_' . $option;
            $optPrice   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $regMKey, true );
        }
        return $optPrice;
    }
    return $price;
}
// Variable
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'return_price_by_option', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'return_price_by_option' , 99, 2 );

function return_price_by_option_variation( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    // delete product cache
    wc_delete_product_transients($variation->get_id());

    // options can be digits like 1, 2, 3, ...
    $option = isset( $_COOKIE['option'] ) ? $_COOKIE['option'] : '';

    if( $option ) {
        $regMKey    = '_sale_price_option_' . $option;
        $optPrice   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $regMKey, true );

        if( empty($optPrice) ) {
            $regMKey    = '_regular_price_option_' . $option;
            $optPrice   = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), $regMKey, true );
        }
        return $optPrice;
    }
    return $price;
}

// Variations
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'return_price_by_option_variation', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'return_price_by_option_variation', 99, 3 );
```